# OPC UA java library

Tags: apache-nifi, opc-ua, milo

I am new to OPC UA standard and being a java developer was trying to search for a good java library for the standard.

I cam across https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java and Eclipse Milo(or digitalpetri).

How does Eclipse Milo compare with UA-Java? which one should I choose?

My use case is to develop a NIFI(nifi.apache.org) custom processor that can read data from an OPC UA server like Kepware and channel that data into our bigdata store and later build analytics on top of it.  I want to implement OPC features like subscription and historical data access as well in the processor.

Answer (score 4):

I may be a little biased as I'm the primary author of Eclipse Milo, but you should use it because it's both a stack and SDK implementation of OPC UA where the code provided by the foundation is only a stack.

If you don't have extensive knowledge of OPC UA and time to write a lot of code that SDKs have typically already written then you don't want just a stack.

Answer (score 2):

You might find these links on the subject helpful to your effort
  https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/90355/collect-data-from-opc-ua-protocol.html

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/88649/control-system-data-from-kepware.html